# Intellij - add dependency on another plugin

Tags: gradle, intellij-plugin

I am trying to implement a Golang code generation/auto completion plugin for Intellij using the PSI, so I need to add a dependency on my Golang plugin. This looks like what I want to do - https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_dependencies.html

Now the question is how can I figure out id and name and version of the plugin Im using?
[It does not seem to be anywhere in the plugin preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwjbu.png)

The PSI elements are of com.goide.psi.impl.GoTypeImpl class and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to get a plugin id. You can check `plugin.xml` to get it. For Go Plugin it's `org.jetbrains.plugins.go`.

Versions can be found on [plugin page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9568-go/versions).

Comment: downloading the plugin zip and checking the plugin.xml was the right answer. Added the plugin as 'org.jetbrains.plugins.go:182.4505.32.913', which gave me the classes I needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do it.

Both `version` and `xmlId` can be found on the [particular plugin update page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9568-go/update/63620):

[image: update plugin page]